# `not-found.js` not called in Next.js v13.5.4, Node v20.5.1

Tags: next.js

As seen from the question tag, I am using the latest versions of Next.js and Node.js at the time of the question. The [`not-found.js` docs of Next.js](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/file-conventions/not-found) clearly states here:

> **Good to know:** In addition to catching expected `notFound()` errors, the root `app/not-found.js` file also handles any unmatched URLs for your whole application. This means users that visit a URL that is not handled by your app will be shown the UI exported by the `app/not-found.js` file.

I am running on the default host and port of Next.js in development (`http://localhost:3000`), and this is my project structure in `src`:

```
.
├── app
│   ├── (backend)
│   └── (frontend)
│       ├── favicon.ico
│       ├── globals.css
│       ├── layout.js
│       ├── not-found.js
│       ├── page.js
│       └── page.module.css
├── components
├── config
├── db
└── lib
```

However, when I navigate to a non-existing url, say `http://localhost:3000/abc`, Next.js default `404` page is shown instead of the one I created in the `app` directory (`not-found.js`). Please, why is this, what am I not doing right?